# elements on ellipse edge in d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I try put images to oval edge. But they are to a large extent on the poles. I have oval:

```
  var oval = group.append("ellipse")
            .attr("cx", this.svgWidth / 2)
            .attr("cy", this.svgHeight / 2)
            .attr("rx", this.rx)
            .attr("ry", this.ry)
            .style("stroke", "#BCBBB6")
            .style("stroke-width", "3px")
            .style("fill", "transparent");
```

and i have image coordinates:

```
var imgX = Math.cos(that.angle * j) * that.rx - this.model.radius;
var imgY = Math.sin(that.angle * j) * that.ry - this.model.radius;
```

How can I arrange them evenly? [image]

Comment: can you make some explanation to the question.?

Comment: `this.angle = Math.PI * 2 / (this.circleData.length);var that = this;  for (var j = 0; j < length; j++) {...}`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I generate a set of evenly distributed points around an ellipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972331/how-can-i-generate-a-set-of-evenly-distributed-points-around-an-ellipse)

Comment: I think the Gabriel's answer was right, it is better to mark that as the best answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add image to `ellipse` tag but you can set image to ellipse background, to add picture to position you mention, Create `circle` then set image to background of them like this :

```
var oval = group.append("ellipse")
        .attr("cx", this.svgWidth / 2)
        .attr("cy", this.svgHeight / 2)
        .attr("rx", this.rx)
        .attr("ry", this.ry)
        .style("stroke", "#BCBBB6")
        .style("stroke-width", "3px")
        .style("fill", "transparent");

oval.selectAll("circle")
        .append("circle")
        .attr("cx" ,imgX )
        .attr("cy",imgY)
        .attr("r","8px")
        .attr("fill","Url(#img)");

var imgX = Math.cos(that.angle * j) * that.rx - this.model.radius;
var imgY = Math.sin(that.angle * j) * that.ry - this.model.radius;
```

**Update1**

To get the real position you have to change Polar angle to Cartesian.

```
var imgX = Math.cos((that.angle)*Math.PI * j/180.0) * that.rx - this.model.radius;
var imgY = Math.sin((that.angle)*Math.PI * j/180.0) * that.ry - this.model.radius;
```

**Update 2**

I create a sample like you asked, Hope to help you.

```
    var width = 600, height = 600;
    var rx = 200, ry = 150;
    var circleNumbers = 20;

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width).attr("height", height)
        .attr("transform", "translate(0,150)");

    var ellipse = svg.append("ellipse")
        .attr("cx", width / 2)
        .attr("cy", height / 2)
        .attr("rx", rx)
        .attr("ry", ry)
        .style("stroke", "#BCBBB6")
        .style("stroke-width", "3px")
        .style("fill", "transparent");
    var degree = 360 / circleNumbers;

    for (var i = 0; i < circleNumbers; i++) {
        var circlePosition = polarToCartesian(width / 2, height / 2, rx, ry, i * degree);
        svg.append("circle")
            .attr("cx", circlePosition.x)
            .attr("cy", circlePosition.y)
            .attr("r", "8px")
            .attr("fill", "red");
    }
```

This function return position on ellipse with specific degree:

```
     function polarToCartesian(centerX, centerY, radiusX, radiusY, angleInDegrees) {

        var angleInRadians = (angleInDegrees* Math.PI / 180.0);


        return {
            x: centerX + (radiusX * Math.cos(angleInRadians)),
            y: centerY + (radiusY * Math.sin(angleInRadians))
        };
    }
```

Complete jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zzjebraeil/xLw9f2j1/).

**Update 3**

I made some changes to `PolarToCartesian()` function and it make the ellipse better.I changed the begin Angle to `-90` and it's seem better.

```
        function polarToCartesian(centerX, centerY, radiusX, radiusY, angleInDegrees) {

        var angleInRadians = ((angleInDegrees-90)* Math.PI / 180.0);


        return {
            x: centerX + (radiusX * Math.cos(angleInRadians)),
            y: centerY + (radiusY * Math.sin(angleInRadians))
        };
    }
```

Complete jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zzjebraeil/Lfszwmao/).

Comment: i know it! But the circles gets close to the poles , and the middle is empty

Comment: If still have problem update your question with your complete code to find error, here is some parameter that I don't know what is it such as : `j` or `rx` or `radius`.

Comment: `this.rx = this.svgWidth / 2 - 50;
this.ry = this.svgHeight / 2 - 80;
radius = 50;` and J - iterator to loop through an array with data for pictures

Comment: See the Update 2 of my Answer.

Comment: @Gabrel Thank you! Your variant is better, but if ellipse is big, most circles still near the pole - http://jsfiddle.net/xLw9f2j1/2/

Comment: It's because of the different between `rx `and `ry`. if they have little difference ellipse will be like circle and all the circle will  arrange in same difference. could you explain what exactly you looking for?

Comment: Please check Update 3.